# Left Join in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, left-join

I have the following query which was working fine in Oracle and I have replaced the `(+)` key word with `left join`.. It's not working in SQL Server 2008.

Please help me: what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    ARM_KEYID, ARD_KEYID, FCT_FACTORYID, FCT_NAME, 
    AUC_AUDITTYPEID, ATM_DESCRIPT, LIN_LINEID, LIN_DESCRIPTION, 
    CEL_CELLID, CEL_DESCRIPTION,ARM_EMPID, AUDITOR.EMP_NAME,         
    ARM_REPDATE, AUC_WEEKNO,AUC_FROMDATE, AUC_TILLDATE,
    (SELECT OPD_DESCRIPT 
     FROM OPERATIONSDETAILS OPD 
     WHERE OPD.OPD_KEYID = OPDDETAILS.OPD_PARENTID),
    OPD_OPNO, OPD_DESCRIPT,
    CLD_OPNO, CLD_DESCRIPT, ALM_KEYID,
    CASE 
       WHEN ALD_PRIORITY = 'H' THEN 'High' 
       WHEN ALD_PRIORITY = 'M' THEN 'Medium'
       WHEN ALD_PRIORITY = 'L' THEN 'Low'
    END AS ALD_PRIORITY,
    ARD_FEEDBACK, ARD_NCCLASSIFICATION, ALD_NCACTION,
    OWNER.EMP_NAME, dpt_description , ALD_TARGETDATE, 
    COMPLETED.EMP_NAME, ALD_COMPLETIONDATE, ALD_COMPREMARKS,
    CASE 
       WHEN ALD_STATUS = 'Y' 
          THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, ALD_COMPLETIONDATE, ALD_TIMESTAMP) 
          ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ALD_TIMESTAMP) 
    END AS PENDING_DAYS,
    CASE 
       WHEN ALD_STATUS = 'Y' THEN 'COMPLETED' 
       WHEN ALD_STATUS = 'N' THEN 'PENDING' 
    END AS LAD_STATUS  
FROM 
    AUDITREPORTMASTER, AUDITREPORTDETAILS,
    CHECKLISTDETAILS, AUDITCALENDAR, OPERATIONSMASTER, 
    OPERATIONSDETAILS OPDDETAILS, ACTIONLISTMASTER, 
    ACTIONLISTDETAILS, AUDITTYPEMASTER, CELLMASTER, EMPLOYEEMASTER AUDITOR, EMPLOYEEMASTER OWNER,
    EMPLOYEEMASTER COMPLETED, FACTORYMASTER,LINEMASTER, departmentmaster  
WHERE 
    ARD_NCSTATUS = 'N' 
    AND ARD_RECNO = '1' 
    AND AUC_ACTIVE = 'Y'
    AND ARM_KEYID = ARD_MASTERID 
    AND CLD_KEYID = ARD_CKDETAILID 
    AND AUC_KEYID = ARM_CALENDARID  
    AND AUC_OPDKEYID = OPD_KEYID 
    AND OPM_KEYID = OPD_OPMASTERID 
    AND ATM_KEYID = AUC_AUDITTYPEID 
    AND CEL_CELLID = AUC_LINEID 
    AND LIN_LINEID = AUC_SECTIONID 
    AND ARM_EMPID = AUDITOR.EMP_EMPLOYEEID 
    AND ALD_OWNER =* OWNER.EMP_EMPLOYEEID  
    AND DPT_DEPARTMENTID *= OWNER.emp_departmentid  
    AND ALD_COMPLETEDBY =* COMPLETED.EMP_EMPLOYEEID 
    AND FCT_FACTORYID = AUC_FACTORYID  
    AND ALD_AUDITDETAILID  = ARD_KEYID 
    AND ALM_KEYID  = ALD_MASTERID
    AND ARM_ACTIVE = 'Y' 
    AND AUC_AUDITTYPEID = 'ATM/01' 
ORDER BY 
    FCT_FACTORYID, OPM_AUDITTYPEID, CEL_CELLID, ARM_REPDATE;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. Also using the `*=` and `=*` for defining joins **will be removed** from SQL Server very soon - get rid of that old habit!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? In first glance it seems there is one issue in where clause, there is unwanted * in the condition
*AND ALD_OWNER =* OWNER.EMP_EMPLOYEEID*

Comment: Actually I have replaced Oracle Query with (+) operator to left and right join but  its show an error like "Query contains an outer-join request that is not permitted." This error comes only for *= left outer join in sql server 2008.. Pls help me

Comment: It is the syntax issue, try changing the syntax as mentioned in the below link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21171836/Query-contains-an-outer-join-request-that-is-not-permitted-Sybase-to-SQL-Server-conversion.html

Comment: Modified the query as per the link shared but not achieved the rsult.. some error..